# Обрезка string при помощи strpos, substr

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Вопрос по PHP. Есть такая строка: 7 х 17 ET50, в которой значения цифр могут меняться. Мне нужно найти такую функцию, которая бы обрезала, например, цифры после "х" и до "ЕТ". Я пробовал вот так: `$d5[0] = substr($d5[0], strpos($d5[0], 'x'), 4);` Но такая конструкция обрезает цифры ВМЕСТЕ с иксом, а икс мне не нужен.

Comment: Что у вас из строки `7 х 17 ET50` в результате должно получиться? А смотреть наверное стоит в сторону регулярных выражений.

Comment: Как бы это объяснить)) Там сайт готовый, но просят сделать так, чтобы вот эти цифры брались из базы (они в ней целиком такой строкой записаны), затем каждая из этих цифр резалась на ссылку, потом при клике с главной создавалась отдельная страница, на которой показывались бы все значения из базы, подходящие выбранному авто, а вот эти цифры в виде ссылок при клике закидывались в форму на другой странице и уже там автоматом из базы показывались диски с заданным параметром. В общем, жесть)) Там уже почти все сделано (с шинами я разобрался), нужно только разрезать эту строку.

Comment: Я уже и стропос-ы, и стрстр-ы, и стррпос-ы - чего только не перепробовал. Либо берет с иксом, либо после икса сразу все, либо вообще не отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: а что, тупо strpos(...)+1 не помогает ?

Comment: Не пробовали посмотреть в сторону http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=pcre -- там это несложно делается?

Comment: mike, А, что, так можно было?))) Да, работает. Спасибо =))

Answer (score 1):

Вот так ваша задача решается:

```
$str = '7 х 17 ET50';
$pattern = "/х (\d+) ET/i";
preg_match($pattern, $str , $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

Здесь выбираются только цифры.

Comment: Большое спасибо и за такое решение, но пользователь под ником Mike предложил просто добавить "+1" за скобкой стрпоса)) Все было так просто

Comment: Я просто обратил внимание, что в случае 4-х значного числа, например, ваша конструкция поломается (поскольку в 4 символа от "х"  вы уже не укладываетесь). Надо будет считать местонахождение подстроки "ET", а это делает код настолько громоздким и сложным, что лучше сразу сделать нормально.

Comment: А там не будет 4-значного числа. Даже 3-значного не будет. Там только 2-значные, т.к. это значения диаметра колесного диска автомобиля, а диски более 100 дюймов сложно представить)) Поэтому код получается по логике "обрезать все до икса, затем после икса на 2 значения и обрезать все после ЕТ". Просто в конечном счете ваш вариант будет намного более громоздким, т.к. это решение влезает в 1 строчку, а в вашем случае надо 3. Но все-равно спасибо, я этот способ запомню на будущее

Comment: Ну, уж что-то не стоит в php делать, так это минимизировать количество строк:)

Колеса для квадроциклов и тракторов этим скриптом в будущем обрабатывать не придется?